# Static WP website and web app are in different host with one domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wordpress, subdomain, amazon-s3

I don't know if this is the right place to post this but I am so much in deep confusion right now.

I have a static WP website hosted in [Fastcomet](https://www.fastcomet.com/) with a domain name ***[www.hpdc.com](http://www.hpdc.com)*** (namecheap) and also
a web app made in Laravel hosted in AWS (free tier).

Now what I want to achieve is I want to create a subdomain ***[www.app.hpdc.com](http://www.app.hpdc.com)*** that will redirect to my laravel web app. How can I achieve this kind of scenario? Should I add subdomain to Fastcomet or in AWS? and also what is the correct term for this problem so that I can easily search in google for further reference.

I'm a newbie in using AWS.

Any alternative solutions and help are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers!

Comment: if you use namecheap as DNS you should add A type of record to your DNS zone and point your www.app.hpdc.com record to desired ip address (in your case it is going to be AWS machine)

Comment: I believe this link will be useful
https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/319/2237/how-can-i-set-up-an-a-address-record-for-my-domain

Comment: Every domain / subdomain can be hosted in different places simply by pointing DNS at it. You can also use a load balancer like an AWS application load balancer to point different paths on a domain to different sources, such as /blog to S3 and /app to an EC2 instance.